# viewing public status updates for a keyword

Tags: facebook, status

Need some help. Is there anyway (api) using which we can read the public statuses of all the people? I mean i want to search whether a keyword that I want to search has been used by any of the folks in their public status messages. Functionality similar to www.youropenbook.org. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Facebook has a publicly available search or streaming API like Twitter.